# Get distance to next largest floating point number in R

Tags: r, matlab, floating-point

I'm trying to convert a Matlab script to R that uses the [eps() function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com). This function returns the distance to the next largest floating point number. Does anyone know how to do this in R? R has [.Machine$double.eps](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zMachine.html) but this is a constant and cannot be used as a function like eps(). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you show what you've done to try to solve this with a reproducible example and where you've run into a problem?

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed as "too broad". To the OP: if you can assume IEEE 754 floating-point format and semantics (which is generally a fairly safe assumption), `x / (1 - double.neg.eps) - x` returns the appropriate value for all positive, non-subnormal `x`. It's not too hard to extend this to the full range of floats, depending on your needs.

Comment: Consider using Rcpp to access the C++ functions `nextafter`/`nexttoward`.

Comment: Thank you, Mark, that solved my issue perfectly.